# Why is my console complaining about a syntax error

Tags: javascript

I have been following a guide on Udemy on Javascript. The guy who was doing helped me out alot but then i got a syntax error telling me to put in a semi colon. I put it in but then it didnt run properly. Please take a look.

```
function calculateMousePos(evt)
{
var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
var root = document.documentElement;
var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
return 
{
        x:mouseX,
        y:mouseY
};
}
```

Comment: Where specifically? What's the exact error? And please fix your formatting.

Comment: `addEventListener` not `addEventListner`

Comment: Omg lol thank you it worked! :D

Comment: it makes no sense to change the question with something new and remove the old problem.

Comment: If you have a new question, use a new post please. I've rolled back your addition.

Answer (score 2):

In Javascript a return statement must be (at least partially) on the same line as your return value:

```
return {
  x:mouseX,
  y:mouseY
};
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to move the curly baracket of the return object into the same line, because of Javascript's [automatic semicolon insertion (ASI)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846283/what-are-the-rules-for-javascripts-automatic-semicolon-insertion-asi).

The error results of a blocks statement and a second [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label) in it.

```
function calculateMousePos(evt) {
    var rect = canvas.getBoundingClientRect();
    var root = document.documentElement;
    var mouseX = evt.clientX - rect.left - root.scrollLeft;
    var mouseY = evt.clientY - rect.top - root.scrollTop;
    return {
        x: mouseX,
        y: mouseY
    };
}
```

Comment: @D.Kippen, now you changed the question.